# Gradle - Install thirdparty dependencies into local ivy repository

Tags: java, groovy, jar, gradle, ivy

I have a gradle project that has several thirdparty dependencies. At the moment, I have set `mavenCentral()` as a repository to enable me to download the JARs and compile/run etc.

However, I have a local ivy style repository on the filesystem that is being used as a local repository (to control the JARs that developers add, rather than just having mavenCentral available for all JARs to be updated whenever - much like artifactory, but with out the application server stuff).

So I have my PoC working with my dependencies, and I now want to install the currently downloaded set of thirdparty JARs into my local ivy repository, so I can remove the dependency on mavenCentral and all builds just use the local JARs - is there any easy way to install these cached JARs in my ivy repo using gradle?

I have tried using a copyDeps task as below, but that just copies the jars to a flat folder, but I want the ivy folder structure

```
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.runtime
  into '/tmp/lib'
}
```

Is this possible/easy?  (and no, assume I can't drastically change the setup/environment/process :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any easy way to install third-party dependencies and all their metadata (module descriptors, checksums, etc.) into a Maven/Ivy repository using Gradle. It's something you'd have to script on your own. If you go from a Maven to an Ivy repository, you'll also have to convert pom.xml's into ivy.xml's etc.

PS: Don't use a file-based Ivy repository. Artifactory is a *much* better choice, and it's free and easy to set up. I think it's even able to convert pom.xml's into ivy.xml's (but first reconsider if you actually need an Ivy repository).